# Error on GitHub Talend Job with tRESTClient

Tags: talend, rest-client

I'm getting error while executing talend job,
This is my another job,

```
tRESTClient --> tXMLMap --> tLogrow
```

The Error is:

```
Exception in component tRESTClient_1 (GitHubJob)
javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.convertToWebApplicationException(AbstractClient.java:507)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:895)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:426)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.get(WebClient.java:609)
    at local_project.githubjob_0_1.GitHubJob.tRESTClient_1Process(GitHubJob.java:1185)
    at local_project.githubjob_0_1.GitHubJob.tMongoDBConnection_1Process(GitHubJob.java:440)
    at local_project.githubjob_0_1.GitHubJob.runJobInTOS(GitHubJob.java:1982)
[statistics] disconnected
    at local_project.githubjob_0_1.GitHubJob.main(GitHubJob.java:1831)
```

What is the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please add HTTP header like : content-type = "application/json"

Comment: I tried the header type too, but still getting same error.